# How do pentecostal/charismatic churches reconcile their practiced with 1 Corinthians 14:26-27?

Tags: 1-corinthians, spiritual-gifts, ecclesiology

> 1 Corinthians 14
>
> 27. If any man speaks in another language, let there be two, or at the most three, and in turn; and let one interpret.
> 28. But if there is no interpreter, let him keep silent in the assembly, and let him speak to himself and to God.”

(World English Bible)

How do charismatic/pentecostal churches reconcile their practices of speaking in tongues in church with these verses? I have never attended one of these churches, but as far as I am aware, there is rarely, if ever, someone who interprets what is spoken. (Please correct me if I am mistaken. I am not trying to be divisive; I truly want to know how these churches reconcile their beliefs with Scripture.)

Comment: Welcome to SE-C.  Please see the Tour and Help (below, bottom left) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Up-voted +1.

Comment: Related: [Have a message in tongues and its interpretation ever been verified by an outsider fluent in both languages?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84255/50422). Also related (if not a duplicate): [How do Pentecostals or other Charismatics respond to criticisms about 'speaking in tongues' by multiple people at once and without interpretation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84282/50422)

Comment: Yes, that one does answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: @Someone Please close your own question if you already have an answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth how do I do that? I already flagged it as a duplicate.

Comment: There's a close button under the question. Or maybe Delete.

Comment: I have Share Edit Delete Flag. Should I delete it?