# What is the biblical basis for Concentric Cessationism?

Tags: biblical-basis, miracles, spiritual-gifts, cessationism

According to [Monergism.com](https://www.monergism.com/topics/spiritual-gifts/cessationists-view):

> In Christian theology, cessationism is the view that the charismatic gifts of the Holy Spirit, such as tongues, prophecy and healing, ceased being practiced early on in Church history. Cessationists usually believe the miraculous gifts were given only for the foundation of the Church, during the time between the coming of the Holy Spirit on Pentecost, c. AD 33 (see Acts 2) and the fulfillment of God's purposes in history, usually identified as either the completion of the last book of the New Testament or the death of the last Apostle.
> Cessationists are divided into four main groups:
>
> - **Concentric Cessationists** believe that the miraculous gifts have indeed ceased in the mainstream church and evangelized areas, but appear in unreached areas as an aid to spreading the Gospel (Luther and Calvin, though they were somewhat inconsistent in this position).
> - **Classical cessationists** assert that the "sign gifts" such as prophecy, healing and speaking in tongues ceased with the apostles and the finishing of the canon of Scripture. They only served as launching pads for the spreading of the Gospel; as affirmations of God's revelation. However, these cessationists do believe that God still occasionally does miracles today, such as healings or divine guidance, so long as these "miracles" do not accredit new doctrine or add to the New Testament canon. Richard Gaffin, John F. MacArthur and Daniel B. Wallace are perhaps the best-known classical cessationists.
> - **Full Cessationists** argue that along with no miraculous gifts, there are also no miracles performed by God today. This argument, of course, turns on one's understanding of the term, "miracle." B. B. Warfield, J. Gresham Machen, F.N. Lee.
> - **Consistent Cessationists** believe that not only were the miraculous gifts only for the establishment of the first-century church, but the so-called fivefold ministry found in Eph. 4 was also a transitional institution (i.e., There are no more apostles or prophets, but also no more pastors, teachers, or evangelists). For more information, click on Wikipedia.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessationism_versus_continuationism#Types_of_cessationism):

> - **Full cessationists** believe that all miracles have ceased, along with any miraculous gifts.
> - **Classical cessationists** assert that the miraculous gifts such as prophecy, healing, and speaking in tongues ceased with the apostles.
>   However, they do believe that God occasionally works in supernatural
>   ways today.
> - **Consistent cessationists** believe that not only were the miraculous gifts only for the establishment of the first-century
>   church, but the need for apostles and prophets also ceased.
> - **Concentric cessationists** believe that the miraculous gifts have indeed ceased in the mainstream church and evangelized areas, but may
>   appear in unreached areas as an aid to spreading the Gospel. Daniel B.
>   Wallace describes himself as a concentric cessationist and describes
>   the other cessationist viewpoints as "linear".

What is the biblical basis for **Concentric Cessationism**?

**Note:** this question is related to but more specific than [What is the basis for Cessationism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5290/50422) -- I'm specifically interested in the "concentric" branch.

---

Other related questions:

- [What is the biblical basis for Full Cessationism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/90324/50422)
- [How do Cessationists react to a world-view-challenging testimony from a fellow Christian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/90292/50422)
- [How do Cessationists who believe in modern-day miracles judge the credibility of modern miracle claims?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/87434/50422)
- [What is an overview of Christian beliefs regarding which spiritual gifts are still available to the body of Christ and which ones have ceased?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/85911/50422)

Comment: Could you maybe clarify the description of Classical cessationists and Concentric cessationists? To me the differences are not really expressing clearly.

Comment: @Hjan - I quoted an additional source, let me know if it helps.

Comment: The modified version is way clearer. Maybe you should also modify/extend the wikipedia page!